# How to run simple app with koa2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, koa, koa2

**Problem**

I am trying to run simple http server using [koa2](/questions/tagged/koa2), but have problems running it.

It uses [es6](/questions/tagged/es6) that is expected to work in future [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) versions and I was wondering how can I run it with `node v6.1.0` ?

**Code**

```js
import Koa from 'koa';    
const app = new Koa();

// Setup handler.
app.use(async ctx => {
    ctx.body = "Hello World!";
});

// Start server.
app.listen(3000);
```

**Output**

```js
$ node --version
v6.1.0

$ node --harmony index.js
C:\Users\gevor\WebstormProjects\untitled1\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Koa from 'koa';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:511:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:160:18)
    at node.js:445:3
```

**Question**

I want to know how to run my app?

**Similar Issues**

- https://github.com/koajs/koa/issues/621
- https://github.com/koajs/koa/issues/572

Comment: What problems do you have? Is this all the code you have?

Comment: I want know how to set environment to run basic sample with Koa v2 and node v6.1.0.

Comment: Install node.js and run it `node index.js` assuming the code is in index.js. Have you tried?

Comment: You should add this errors to your question. Have you tried to run node with harmony flag `node --harmony index.js`?

Comment: @Molda thanks for suggestion, I just added execution log to question.

Comment: I'm no expert at this but i think that node doesn't support *import, async, await* yet. I quess the only way is to use transpiler such as https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @Molda I found workaround that I was searching for, that includes installing [Babel](http://babeljs.io), thanks Man!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

I was able to find workaround and will describe solution that includes installing [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) module

**Step 1** - Install [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and required presets

```
$ npm install babel-core --save
$ npm install babel-preset-es2015-node5 --save
$ npm install babel-preset-stage-3 --save
```

**Step 2** - Create `index.js` file with `babel-core/register` requirement

```
// set babel in entry file
require('babel-core/register')({
    presets: ['es2015-node5', 'stage-3']
});

require('./app');
```

**Step 3** - Put your sample code inside of `app.js`

```
import Koa from 'koa';    
const app = new Koa();

// Setup handler.
app.use(async ctx => {
    ctx.body = "Hello World!";
});

// Start server.
app.listen(3000);
```

After running `node index.js` server works like a pie and `import`, `async`, `await` are being processed properly.

**References**

- [koa2 sources](https://github.com/koajs/koa/tree/2.0.0)
- [Documentation should include an example of babel configuration](https://github.com/koajs/koa/issues/572)
- [Using Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/)
- [Installation Guide](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/v2.x/docs/api/index.md)

Comment: For the async/await part, you can use a native implementation now that does not require to transpile your code. You need node >= 7, and run your app with --harmony-async-await flag.

There is no native solution yet for the ES6 imports.

Comment: Just to mention, Node 7.6 comes with async/await by default, so no more need for the --harmony-async-await flag :)

Answer (score 2):

Upgraded your node version to at least 7.6 after that there is no need to transpile your code using babel which is highly avoidable in production.Node >7.6 version support async/await which is very powerful.