# Node error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I don't understand what is wrong. I checked other forum talking about transpilation and babel. What do I have to do?

```
node -v
v5.5.0
```

my code:

```
import recast from 'recastai'
```

and the error

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import recast from 'module1'
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:999:3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't run simple app with Koa v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529156/cant-run-simple-app-with-koa-v2)

Comment: @Stefdelec check out this answer see if it answers this better. This needed a revisit https://stackoverflow.com/a/47880185/124486 Please updated the chosen answer if so.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

ES6 imports are a recently introduced feature and the current stable version of Node does not support them yet. Node.js issue tracker has an [open issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/53) for this - but until V8 and Node add support for this feature, you will need to use a transpiler (most popular one being [babel](https://babeljs.io/)) to be able to use imports.

For quickly trying out transpilation, babel provides a web based REPL. [This one](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2&code=import%20recast%20from%20'recastai'%0A) demonstrates your code being transpiled.

The [babel project homepage](https://babeljs.io/)  points to the relevant resources for getting started with Babel and integrating it with your development workflow.

For the simplest setup, visit this [setup page](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) and select CLI in the Babel built-ins section.

This basically involves three simple steps:

1. Install babel-cli : `npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015`
2. Create `.babelrc` configuration file: `echo '{ "presets": ["es2015"] }' > .babelrc`
3. Use the installed module to transpile your source code: `./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d lib`

The aforementioned setup page also illustrates how to add an npm script to simplify the last step. Alternatively you can integrate babel with your editor or build chain so that your files are automatically compiled on change.

Comment: Also, need to: npm install babel-preset-es2015

Answer (score 10):

In case you don't want to deal with babel. This one worked for me.

```
const calc = require('./my_calc');
let {add, multiply} = calc;
```

Answer (score 5):

1) Install the latest presets

```
yarn add --dev babel-preset-latest
```

2) Create `.babelrc` and add the following

```
{
    "presets": ["latest"]
}
```

3) Run your script

```
npx babel-node yourscript.js
```

Or in your `package.json` file add

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "babel-node index.js"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting Started

First we'll install babel-cli.

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

Along with some presets.

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-2
```

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node index.js --presets es2015,stage-2"
  }
```

run:

```
$ npm start
```

Watching file changes with **nodemon**:

We can improve our npm start script with nodemon.

```
$ npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

Then we can update our npm start script.

package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2"
  }
```

run:

```
$ npm start
```

If you are using **pm2**, then follow these steps:

```
$ pm2 start app.js --interpreter babel-node
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple to resolve this issue, `import` is ES6 syntax and Node has difficulty in supporting it, you need to add **Babel** as a transpiler, go to package.json and add the following

First add a script tag to use babel while running the JS code for transpiling.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./app.js --exec babel-node -e js"
  }
```

And then add the following as the Babel devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
  }
```

after this you also need to configure the babel presets file, therefore create **.babelrc** file at the root directory and define the presets as follows

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

Don't forget to do an `npm install` in the end

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a [NodeJS enhancement proposal](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps) we have a path forward. You can use [`@standard-things/esm`](https://github.com/standard-things/esm)

Find the [announcement here](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/08/10/es-modules-node-today/) Simply run

```
npm i --save @std/esm
```

In your packaged today.