# importing functions - NodeJS - non-html

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, visual-studio-2017

I am learning automation for work and currently a little stuck. So far stackoverflow has been a life saver :)

I am writing a test for selenium in visualstudio in javascript (nodes). I understand this is not a great combination but thats what work wants.

I have a test in the app.js file (see screenshot). It references a function in the functions.js file. I cannot get it to recognise the function though. I presume I need to reference the files containing the function. I have tried import 'import cellFromXLS from "functions.js";' and it does not work(Unexpected token import error).

Any ideas on what I can do? Anything fancy like modifying the package.json file to include all files with functions in them?
 I am on the latest node.js and the latest drivers.

Also it seems intellisense does not work for javascript in visual studio. Is this right or anyway to fix it?
[VisualStudio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve7nw.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634198/node-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Comment: In functions.js:    cellFromXLS = function (cellId) {
    //Define sheetNumber 
    var sheetNumber = 0;
    //Define file Path name 
    var fileNamePath = ('trial.xls');
    //NodeJs read file 
    var XLS;
    if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
        XLS = require('xlsjs');
    }
    //Working with workbook 
    var workbook = XLS.readFile(fileNamePath);
    var sheetNamelist = workbook.SheetNames;
    var value = workbook.Sheets[sheetNamelist[sheetNumber]][cellId].v;
    return value;
}; 

module.exports = {
    cellFromXLS
}

Comment: In apps.js:     const functions = require("./functions.js");
functions.cellFromXLS('A1');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node doesn't support `import` natively just yet.

In your functions file you can do something like

```
function blah(){
    console.log("I am blah")
}

function wah(){
    console.log("Wah wah")
}

module.exports = {
    blah,
    wah
}
```

then in `app.js` you can do:

```
const functions = require('./functions.js')
functions.blah()
functions.wah()
```

Comment: I have tried the above but I get a messge saying my function is not defined? I put the export lines in functions.js and the 'const' line in my app.js

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OiRefD7.png

Here is a screenshot of it in action. Is what  you had close to this?

Comment: Not sure then, it's working in my instance and screenshot. Oh well hopefully you get to resolve it.

Comment: started from scratch and got it working with your method :) Thank you very much. Dont think I can up vote yet but really appreciate you help

Answer (score 0):

The error already tells you what's wrong.
You need to use

`const cellFromXLS = require("./functions.js");`

instead of

`import cellFromXLS from "functions.js"`

if you want to use the `import` syntax, check out [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: ok, I dont want to use babel as its extra thing the business has to validate (Very heavily audited industry). I thought nodejs now supported import from version 8? I wil ltry the other way as you suggested.