# Imported component getting: Unexpected token import

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ecmascript-6

My express's app.js loads in my main template file like this:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

Where `routes.index` is:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('Index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

My Index.jsx is my main template which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './layout';
import NetworkCanvas from '../lib/components/NetworkCanvas/Canvas.jsx';

class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <html>
            <head>
              <title>{this.props.title}</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <NetworkCanvas />
            </body>
          </html>
    );
  }
}
```

However, when my localhost:8000 loads I keep getting the error:

```
/MyWebpage/lib/components/NetworkCanvas/Canvas.jsx:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

How is it possible that the `import` statements in my Index.jsx work but the ones in the subcomponent don't?

Note that I'm using [`express-react-views`](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views) for my express engine.

**Edit**: Here's my Canvas.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

class Canvas extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            width: '0',
            height: '0'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <canvas 
                width={this.state.width} 
                height={this.state.height}
                ref={(el) => {this.canvas = el}}>
            </canvas>
        );
    }
}

export default Canvas;
```

**Edit 2:**: Here is my project. Thanks all for the help!

https://github.com/MarksCode/PersonalWebsite

Comment: Why do you have two `return`s in your `render`?

Comment: @jmargolisvt Sorry, miscopied my file.

Comment: @Federkun added.

Comment: Are you transpiling both components?  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37634418/3662110

Comment: @jmargolisvt I'm starting my server using this script: `"pm2 start app.js --watch --interpreter ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node"` and my babel presets are `"react", "env", "es2015"`.

Comment: Could you possibly share your complete `app.js` ? @MarksCode

Comment: @keshavDulal Added. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned the repo and it seems that currently all your `jsx` files or lets say `components` are under `lib` directory.
I moved them under `views` directory and changed the import line as:

```
import NetworkCanvas from './lib/components/NetworkCanvas/Canvas.jsx';
```

and the error gets resolved because the [Docs](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views#views) says that only the files inside `views` directory will be transpiled.

> Only the files in your `views` directory (i.e. `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'))` will be compiled.

Hence the `import` error which you were facing.

***Additional info:***

Once the `import` errors is resolved you will get another error in `Canvas.jsx`
So you will need to add the following at the top of your constructor.

```
super(props);
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw many other projects with a `/lib` directory so got confused. Guess I should learn to read docs better.