# Running Python script with Forever (Node.JS module) restarting every second

Tags: python, node.js, forever

I start my forever with "forever start app.py" and then check with "forever list" and the app is STOPPED and does not restart. When I start it "forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 app.py" it restarts it over and over again every .8 seconds or less. If I run my app outside of forever it works perfectly fine. I've restarted my computer and the same thing happens. Any idea what the problem might be?

I uninstalled forever and even Node.JS and reinstalled and when I tried to forever start again, I came across this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

UPDATE

When I forever stop 0 the stopped process, even though it deletes it, it gives an error that reads:

```
 error:   Forever cannot find process with id: 0
```

After that, when I check forever log, I get:

```
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\log does not exist.
```

I am on Windows 10 and running the latest versions. (Node.js 9.11.1 and NPM 5.6.0). Any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the package? It usually fixes things.

Comment: execute: `forever logs 0` and see errors that cause issue.

Comment: Try this way: `forever start -c "node -r babel-register" app.js`

Comment: I tried it and it still says the app is stopped

Comment: add app.js file to Your question

Comment: According to the first sentence of your question you're trying to start `app.py` not app.js -- can that be the problem? If not, forever could run the wrong version of node.js (wrong nvm?) as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634198/node-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Comment: @Gyuri It used to work before.

Comment: @Gyuri surprisingly Aaron is right. Nodejs module `forever` can execute any code if You use `-c "interpreter code-file.ext"`. But it's funny to see non nodejs world do this trick )))

Comment: @num8er turns out I was also right: a Python script was attempted to be run as javascript -- thus the `Unexpected token import` error. ;)

Comment: @Gyuri off course. If You don't pass custom command it calls nodejs and yes it parses it as JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix Your issue by checking logs.

Execute in terminal:

1) `forever list` and find Your app is running

```
$ forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid      command             script    forever pid   id logfile                         uptime        
data:    [0] UID-HERE /usr/local/bin/node app.js 63123   56557    /home/api/.forever/UID-HERE.log STOPPED
```

2) `forever logs 0`  (0 for `[0]` sequential number in listing) 
    or 
   `forever logs 0 -f` (for continuous reading)

3) Read logs and fix Your issue

I can guess that it may be  `EADDRINUSE` because of port conflict when You run many apps using same port, so if Yes:

make sure that there is no same app.js in listing (`forever list`)

or

execute: `ps -ax | grep node` and see nodejs apps possibly running by maybe other users on system

UPDATE:

Since You're running `python` script using `nodejs` module (`forever`), try to run it like that:

```
forever start -c "python app.py"
```

Comment: I checked and port usage was not the issue. I edited my post and included the error message above

Comment: @AaronMazie seems like You're using Babel in local development, so to run it using forever transpile Your code to usable node code and run it with forever. Or search: `run node babel with forever` in Google

Comment: The app I'm running is actually in Python, which is what I'm familiar with. Also, is Babel something that comes with Node.JS because I didn't download that seperately?

Comment: @AaronMazie You've set tags in Your question: `node.js` and `forever` and You wrote that error says `Unexpected token import` that means in some part of Your code use such line: `import SomePackage from 'some-library'` that is not supported natively by nodejs and it's being converted using transpilers (babel). But now You're saying that You use Python? How come?  Whaaat (:  Can You share `app.js` file in Your question?

Comment: I'm using forever to run a Python script perpetually. It crashes sometimes because of lag errors from the API I'm calling, so I use forever to keep it up. Could the transpiler errors be from my Visual Studio, GCC/G++ compiler? I had updated it. I use both Cython and Python. I've tried both types of scripts with forever and it's the same

Comment: @AaronMazie added example running python script via forever, look at the end of my answer.

Comment: YOU ROCK! It works. Thank you so much for continuing to try to help me. SO appreciated. And I apologize for assuming that app.js and app.py would be the same thing. Used to work the other way before, I don't know what changed. Anyway, thanks so much again

Comment: @AaronMazie no need to apologise) it happens with anyone. glad that it worked.