# Getting error when using `import` in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

**this is my code.**

```
import app  from './core/app'

const PORT=process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.express.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`server up and running on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

**when i am importing my core module from core folder giving this error.**

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import app  from './core/app'
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634198/node-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is, NodeJS environment currently does not support the `import` syntax. We only have one approach to load an external module is using the `require()` function.

Comment: That's right, I use `import` all around the place, but I write Typescript, not Javascript. I had a look at the transpiled code, and all `import` disappear and are replaced with `require`.

Comment: This might be a relevant article for you: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c