# How to make executable of node project?

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, zeit-pkg

I have my project in node.js and express.js. i need to make an executable of node.js project.

**Project configuration :**

Using ES6 features :  import and dynamic import, and for this babel.js , i am using.

**Project status :**

Project is running correctly no problem.

Transpiling of the project is working. That is bundling creation is ok.

**Problem/Error/Issue :**

while packaging with command :

> pkg . --debug

it giving error of ' import'

**package.json configuration :**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "bin": "./app.js",
  "main":"./app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js --exec babel-node",
    "test": "nodemon NODE_ENV=development",
    "build": "webpack --config build/webpack.config.js --progress true --display-error-details true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.6",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "request": "^2.79.0",
    "serve-favicon": "*",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "winston": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "nodemon": "*",
    "pkg": "^4.3.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "pkg": {
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/*",
      "build/output/main.bundle.js"
    ],
    "assets": [
      "views/**/*",
      "public/*"
    ],
    "targets": [
      "node8"
    ]
  }
}
```

**webapck.config.js :**

```
module.exports = {
   node: {
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true
 },
 target: 'node',
  mode: 'development', 
  entry: ["./app.js"],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'output')    
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".js",".json"]
        },
        use: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: [
                    '@babel/preset-env'                   
                 ],
                 plugins: [
                    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
                 ]
            }
        }]
      }
    ],
    exprContextRegExp: /$^/,
    exprContextCritical: false
  }
};
```

**Error that i am getting :**

```
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node8-x64 for file C:\snapshot\server\app\modules\v1\user\routes\routes.js
C:\snapshot\server\app\modules\v1\user\routes\admin-routes.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Socket.<anonymous> ([eval]:18:19)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:597:20)
C:\snapshot\pickcel-server\app\modules\v1\user\routes\admin-routes.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {
                                                              ^^^^^^
```

What will be the reason ??

Can someone give some suggestion or strategy ?

Regards

Comment: Are you running `pkg . --debug` from inside the `output` directory? That's where the transpiled code is saved.

Comment: May be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634198/node-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Comment: @robertklep   no,   i am running "pkg . --debug" from root directory of project.

Comment: @uds `pkg .` will use the `bin` property of `package.json` (in your case `app.js`) and use that as entry file. I assume that that file isn't transpiled. Try `pkg build/output/main.bundle.js` (or `pkg output/main.bundle.js`, not sure exactly where your bundle file lives)

Comment: @robertklep Thanks dude. I just changed the entry to bundled file. and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

`pkg .` will use the `bin` property of `package.json` and use that to determine the entry file, which in your case is `app.js`.

Assuming that that file isn't transpiled, and you want to package the transpiled bundle, try this:

```
pkg build/output/main.bundle.js --debug
```