# How can I create a executable file from a Node JS project?

Tags: node.js, pkg-config

I'm working in a Node JS project, which takes an API, creates objects and saves them into a DB, everything works in it fine, as you can see in one past [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358386/how-can-i-insert-objects-in-sql-server-running-a-function-in-a-loop-connectione) I made.

Now I need to create a executable file of it to run it, so I searched about it and found [PKG](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).

The thing is that I installed the package using `npm i pkg`, and then I ran `pkg app.mjs` and I got a lot of error messages, all of them look like this:

> Warning Failed to make bytecode node16-x64 for file C:\snapshot\weather\node_modules\fetch-blob\file.js

So, I searched and found that I had to use `pkg . --debug` to look for the error, and showed me that I had to add a bin property, so I added it in my package.json, which looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "bin": "./app.mjs",
  "module": "CommonJS",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.mjs",
    "dev": "nodemon app.mjs"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "nexe": "^4.0.0-beta.19",
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.0",
    "pkg": "^5.5.2",
    "tedious": "^14.0.0"
  }
}
```

I ran the debug comman and at the end It showed my this error:

> C:\snapshot\weather\node_modules\formdata-polyfill\esm.min.js:3
> import C from 'fetch-blob'
> ^^^^^^
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

[image]

As you can see, my files were created, when I tried to open them, none of them does something, as they should make some inserts into a DB.

So I would like to know how can I fixed, because I tried what I saw in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697856/how-to-make-executable-of-node-project) and this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/641) but nothing solved my problem.

Have somebody created a .exe from Node JS using this? Do you know what causes the error and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I continued searching and watch the [issue](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/641#issuecomment-1026079073) in Github, so I can't use PKG because apparently this can't be done with ES Modules (imports).

So I decided to look at other options and found about [Nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe), so I decided to change into it, I followed all the instructions I saw in this [tutorial](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/compile-your-nodejs-application-into-a-exe-file/#nexe), and wrote:

```
nexe app.mjs
```

And I got this error:

> i nexe 4.0.0-beta.19
> √ Downloading pre-built Node.js
> √ Finished in 1.539s
> Error: https://github.com/nexe/nexe/releases/download/v3.3.3/windows-x64-14.17.6 is not available, create it using the --build flag
> See nexe -h for usage..

Can anyone tell me some way I can create a exe file from a ES Module? Or what am I doing wrong? I checked my Node JS version and I don't think it is something about it, but if needed, I'm working in v14.17.6.

I watched this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app) Wyck told me, but it didn't solve my problem either. If any extra explanation is needed, let me know.

Comment: Slightly more relevant question than the one you linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app

Comment: Let me take a look @Wyck

Answer (score 2):

1. pkg should be in devDependencies
2. scripts should be in package.json
   `"build:win": "npx pkg ./start.js -c package.json -t node14-win-x64",`
3. Add to package.json `"pkg": { "assets": [], "targets": [ "node14-win-x64", "node12-macos-x64" ], "outputPath": "./dist" }`
4. Add to assets some files if you need it inside *.exe