# Cannot use es6 import and export with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, babeljs

I am using convictjs to manage the configuration files for my nodejs application.  The file that has the configuration schema is called "config.js" and it is in the "config" folder.

I am using es6 import and export statements

```
import convict from "convict";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import configDev from "./config.dev";
import configProd from "./config.prod";
import configStage from "./config.stage";
.
.
.
export default config.getProperties();
```

These configuration files contain database credentials and other necessary database information, which I use in the "index.js" for the sequelize models.

Note:  Early on in the development process we tried using es6 with sequelize ran into other problems so we opted to using es5 for models, migrations and seeds.

Currently whenever I try to execute migrations, seuqlize throws an error as shown below

```
ERROR: Error reading "config\config.js". Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
import
```

Babel is setup properly, I can transpile and run the application  without any issues except for database migrations.  Any help to resolve this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634198/node-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Node.js does not support this syntax yet so you should either use `require` or transpile your code with babel before the execution.

**UPD:** seems like it's possible to enable ES6 modules in Node.js starting from v10.12.0 https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

```
node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs
```

Comment: I am traspiling my code, the whole application aside from the sequelize scripts is written in es6.

Comment: My npm script is this,
"babel-node --presets env ./app.js --nodeEnv dev" 

this transpiles the code and starts the application

Comment: @KaanYalti then, for some reason, this module is not transpiled. Anyway I would not recommend using ES6 modules in node js for now.

Comment: @KaanYalti you are saying that the problem occurs when you try to execute migrations. How are you executing them?

Comment: Through a npm script that basically executes this "sequelize db:migrate:undo:all".

Comment: @KaanYalti seems like here sequelize is importing your config file without transpiling.

Comment: I think that is the problem; however, I don't know how to fix it.  I am currently looking into modifying the npm scipt I mentioned above to call babel-node before executing the migrations, but so far no success

Comment: @KaanYalti you can use require in your `config.js` (it should work as expected with ES6 modules as well) or you could precompile your project and point sequelize to your dist folder

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already switched to common js in my config file.  That resolved the issue

Comment: hi @KaanYalti can you how you to config your js for import and export witth Sequalize ?? i always failed ,

Comment: @koplweou We actually ended up converting the whole application to typescript before I was able to fix this issue.  But What you can do is run the sequelize scripts through babel and then execute the migrations and seeds; so transpile them, and then run them