# Router is not defined in KOA2

Tags: node.js, koa-router, koa2

I have two files, one of them is the app.js and the otherone is api.js. 
In the first file I have :

```
  app.use(setHeader)
  app.use(api.routes())
  app.use(api.allowedMethods())
```

And in api.js I have:

```
import KoaRouter from 'koa-router';
const api = new Router();

//Validatekey
const validateKey = async (ctx, next) => {
const { authorization } = ctx.request.headers;
console.log(authorization);
if (authorization !== ctx.state.authorizationHeader) {
  return ctx.throw(401);
}
   await next();
}

api.get('/pets', validateKey, pets.list);
```

When I run the project a error message is throw: Router is not defined.

But If I write both files together, the application go fine.

Anybody knows the problem?

I have solved with **var Router = require('koa-router')**

Comment: It was solved, I have change import koaRouter from 'koa-router' by var Router = require('koa-router')

Comment: If you are interested you can make `import` work too by using `babel` transformers.

Answer (score 2):

The import is currently not implemented in nodejs, neither is it supported in the latest ES2015(ES6).
You will need to use a transpiler like Babel to use import in code.I advice that avoid transpiler as it cause performance issues on production just go with require and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Nodejs does not support `import` / `export` syntax and using `require` will solve your problem.

However it is possible to make `import` work on Node.js by using `babel` transformers.

Look the following answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/37601577/972240

Comment: Yes I know,  I use babel transformer but I don't know why  the error continued.